# Configuring React Router 5 with Webpack not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, react-router-dom, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to create web pack build for react application my configuration looks like below.

But when I tried to run the build file in .net application. Router components are not working.

I tried these solutions which is already available, still not working.

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  }
```

```
output: {
    ...
    publicPath: "/"
    ...
  }
```

package.json :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.3.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/d3": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.17",
    "antd": "^4.16.13",
    "axios": "^0.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.3",
    "craco-less": "^1.20.0",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
    "d3": "^7.1.1",
    "less-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "source-map-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.3",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  }
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",
  target: "web",
  mode: "development",
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  output: {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../Scripts"),
    filename: "reactWebpackOutput.js",
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  resolve: {
    // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".css", ".svg"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "ts-loader",
            options: {
              transpileOnly: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        enforce: "pre",
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "source-map-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sass|less|css)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader",
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
          },
          {
            loader: "less-loader",
            options: {
              lessOptions: {
                javascriptEnabled: true,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
        use: ["url-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

app.tsx :

```
<Router>
  <CustomHeader />
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/about">
      <About />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>;
```

What I'm missing ?

Comment: Define 'not working'

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera when you try to navigate with webpack build the router contents won't be visible. So resolved it with HashRouter.